# How to plot a dagger symbol in text in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a plot with a title at the top which is generated using text. I am not using main as I have a custom graphics window. This title, for the purposes of this demonstration needs to look like this:

ID: #### (n = 15)

Where '####' and '15' are extracted from a dataframe/list. However at the end of this, I would like to plot a super-scripted dagger symbol, so the (n = 15) is to the power of dagger essentially. I know the dagger symbol can be obtained by using symbol("\206") and I know I can use something along the lines of expression, or substitute(symbol("\206"))[2]. I just can't seem to get it to be super-scripted.

Any ideas?

Comment: `plot(1:10, main=expression(ID~23566~(n==15)^"\206"))` can display a dagger symbol as a superscript. But you said you are not using `main=`, I am not sure if it is still applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, that doesn't work. The full code I tried was:
`text(expression(ID~gsub("[+]","*",op)~(n = x$stats$N[inc])^if (all(data.$pooled == 1)) "\206"), x=60, y=usr[4]*1.05, adj = 0, cex = 1.5, xpd=TRUE)`